# Entity Framework: Linq query finds entries by original data but returns reference to changed entry

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework

I just spent some days now to find a bug caused by some strange behavior of the Entity Framework (version 4.4.0.0). For an explanation I wrote a small test program. At the end you'll find some questions I have about that.

### Declaration

Here we have a class "Test" which represents our test dataset. It only has an ID (primary key) and a "value" property. In our TestContext we implement a DbSet Tests, which shall handle our "Test" objects as a database table.

```
public class Test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

### Initialization

Now, we remove any (if existent) entries from our "Tests" table and add our one and only "Test" object. It has ID=1 (primary key) and value=10.

```
// Create a new DBContext...
TestContext db = new TestContext();

// Remove all entries...
foreach (Test t in db.Tests) db.Tests.Remove(t);
db.SaveChanges();

// Add one test entry...
db.Tests.Add(new Test { ID = 1, value = 10 });
db.SaveChanges();
```

### Tests

Finally, we run some tests. We select our entry by it's original value (=10) and we change the "value" of our entry to 4711. BUT, we do not call db.SaveChanges(); !!!

```
// Find our entry by it's value (=10)
var result = from r in db.Tests
             where r.value == 10
             select r;
Test t2 = result.FirstOrDefault();

// change its value from 10 to 4711...
t2.value = 4711;
```

Now, we try to find the (old) entry by the original value (=10) and do some tests on the results of that.

```
// now we try to select it via its old value (==10)
var result2 = from r in db.Tests
             where r.value == 10
             select r;

// Did we get it?
if (result2.FirstOrDefault() != null && result2.FirstOrDefault().value == 4711)
{
    Console.WriteLine("We found the changed entry by it's old value...");
}
```

When running the program we'll actually see "We found the changed entry by it's old value...". That means we have run a query for r.value == 10, found something... This would be acceptable. BUT, get receive the already changed object (not fulfilling value == 10)!!!

**Note:** You'll get an empty result set for "where r.value == 4711".

In some further testing, we find out, that the Entity Framework always hands out a reference to the same object. If we change the value in one reference, it's changed in the other one too. Well, that's ok... but one should know it happens.

```
Test t3 = result2.FirstOrDefault();    
t3.value = 42;
if (t2.value == 42)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Seems as if we have a reference to the same object...");
}
```

### Summary

When running a LINQ query on the same Database Context (without calling SaveChanges()) we will receive references to the same object, if it has the same primary key. The strange thing is: Even, if we change an object we will find it (only!) by it's old values. But we will receive a reference to the already changed object. This means that the restrictions in our query (value == 10) is not guaranteed for any entries that we changed since our last call of SaveChanges().

### Questions

Of course, I'll probably have to live with some effects here. But I, would like to avoid to "SaveChanges()" after every little change. Especially, because I would like to use it for transaction handling... to be able to revert some changes, if something goes wrong.

I would be glad, if anyone could answer me one or even both of the following questions:

1. Is there a possibility to change the behavior of entity framework to work as if I would communicate with a normal database during a transaction? If so... how to do it?
2. Where is a good resource for answering "How to use the context of entity framework?" which answers questions like "What can I rely on?" and "How to choose the scope of my DBContext object"?

### EDIT #1

Richard just explained how to access the original (unchanged) database values. While this is valuable and helpful I've got the urge to clarify the goal ...

Let's have a look at what happens when using SQL. We setup a table "Tests":

```
CREATE TABLE Tests (ID INT, value INT, PRIMARY KEY(ID));
INSERT INTO Tests (ID, value) VALUES (1,10);
```

Then we have a transaction, that first looks for entities whose values are 10. After this, we update the value of these entries and look again for those entries. In SQL we already work on the updated version, so we will not find any results for our second query. After all we do a "rollback", so the value of our entry should be 10 again...

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT ID, value FROM Tests WHERE value=10; {1 result}
UPDATE Tests SET value=4711 WHERE ID=1; {our update}

SELECT ID, value FROM Tests WHERE value=10; {no result, as value is now 4711}

ROLLBACK; { just for testing transactions... }
```

I would like to have exactly this behavior for the Entity Framework (EF), where db.SaveChanges(); is equivalent to "COMMIT", where all LINQ queries are equivalent to "SELECT" statements and every write access to an entity is just like an "UPDATE". I don't care about when the EF does actually calls the UPDATE statement, but it should behave the same way as using a SQL Database the direct way... Of course, if "SaveChanges()" is called and returning successfully it should be guaranteed that all data was persisted correctly.

Note: Yes, I could call db.SaveChanges() before every query, but then I would loose the possibility for a "Rollback".

Regards,

Stefan

Comment: Stefan, you can start a transaction in code and call db.SaveChanges multiple times. Thats a way to achive the same behaviour as in your SQL example.

Comment: No, that's like "COMMIT;" after the first "UPDATE"... I would like to: (1) have the possibility to ROLLBACK everything. In our example also revert "UPDATE Tests SET value=4711 WHERE ID=1;" and (2) at the same time receiving 0 results in the second query "SELECT ID, value FROM Tests WHERE value=10;"

Comment: No, thats not true. Inside an own transaction, SubmitChanges will just send the update commands and no commit. You have to commit your Transaction before changes are written to the database.

Comment: You wrote "db.SaveChanges" not "SubmitChanges"... but "SubmitChanges" sounds reasonable. A db.SubmitChanges() doesn't compile... but I found it in the reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx). Therefore, I'll check this out in more detail. Will let you know the result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your updates in a transaction to achive the same result as in your SQL example:

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{

    var result = from r in db.Tests
                    where r.value == 10
                    select r;
    Test t2 = result.FirstOrDefault();

    // change its value from 10 to 4711...
    t2.value = 4711;
    // send UPDATE to Database but don't commit transcation
    db.SaveChanges();

    var result2 = from r in db.Tests
                    where r.value == 10
                    select r;
    // should not return anything
    Trace.Assert(result2.Count() == 0);

    // This way you can commit the transaction:
    // transaction.Complete();

    // but we do nothing and after this line, the transaction is rolled back
}
```

For more information see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: THAT'S IT! I just tested this... and it exactly does what I want. Thank's a lot!

Comment: My problem was: I thought, that a DBContext was implicitly a "TransactionScope" and SaveChanges() would be the "Commit". So I just need to wrap every transaction using a TransactionScope() and just call db.SaveChanges() where it seems to be needed... at least  before calling any linq query.

Comment: Yes, when you don't start an own transaction, EF will span a transaction over SaveChanges().

Comment: I'm using this method, but the transaction.Complete() method behaves weirdly when there are errors. If an integrity constraint is not ok for example, it will silently fail to insert the row but it will commit the rest of the operations, which doesn't allow me to handle the error. is there a way to make it fail when something is wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, Entity Framework tracks the entities it has loaded, and returns the same reference for each query which accesses the same entity. This means that the data returned from your query matches the current in-memory version of the data, and not necessarily the data in the database.

If you need to access the database values, you have several options:

1. Use a new `DbContext` to load the entity;
2. Use [`.AsNoTracking()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679169%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to load an un-tracked copy of your entity;
3. Use [`context.Entry(entity).GetDatabaseValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.getdatabasevalues%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to load the property values from the database;

If you want to overwrite the properties of the local entity with the values from the database, you'll need to call [`context.Entry(entity).Reload()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reload%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: Even this already helps, my goal is not to access the "database" version, but to already execute a query based on a "merged" version of database content and in-memory values. As it would happen during a normal database transaction:
CREATE TABLE Tests (ID INT, value INT, PRIMARY KEY(ID));
INSERT INTO Tests (ID, value) VALUES (1,10);

START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ID, value FROM Tests WHERE value=10;
{1 result}
UPDATE Tests SET value=4711 WHERE ID=1;

SELECT ID, value FROM Tests WHERE value=10;
{no result}
COMMIT;  -- If I call db.SaveChanges(); after changes I'll loose the possibility for Rollback.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the expression tree. The Entity Framework executes your query to the database when you say `SaveChanges()`, as you allready mentioned. When manipulating something within the context, the changes do not happen on the database, they happen in your physical memory. Just when you call `SaveChanges()` your actions are translated to let's say SQL.

When you do a simple `select` the database is queried just in the moment when you acces the data. So if your have not call `SaveChanges()`, it finds the dataset in the database with (SQL)`SELECT* FROM Test WHERE VALUE = 10` but interprets from the expression tree, that it has to be `value == 4711`.

The transaction in EF is happening in your storage. Everything you do before `SaveChanges()` is your transaction. Read for further information: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738523%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

A really good ressource, which is probably up to date, for infomations about the EF is the [Microsoft Data Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef)